# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined (line 15)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to change the format of a date in bestandrange[x][1] to display the calendar week but I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined (line 15)

My guess is that I messed up in defining my Range bestandrange but I'm not quite sure.

My code:

```
function Test(){
  var bestand = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bestand");
  var rowb = 20;
  var columnb = 1;
  var rowcountb = (bestand.getLastRow()+1)-rowb;
  var columncountb = 2;
  var bestandrange = bestand.getRange(rowb, columnb, rowcountb, columncountb).getValues();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(bestandrange[rowb+rowcountb-1][columncountb-1] , "CEST", "w");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays start from  index 0. If `rowcountb` is 4, the range got is A20:B24, which translates to a 2D array of height 4 and bredth 2. So,

```
bestandrange[rowb+rowcountb-1]//bestandrange[20+4-1]
```

`bestandrange[23]` doesn't exist and is `undefined`. `bestandrange[23][1]` will throw `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`.

Comment: Hey TheMaster,
thanks for your fast help. it worked :)